# Sed replace a string with ca certs

Tags: sed

I have yaml file with have parameter like this

```
caCertificates: {}
```

and I want replace it with below contents

```
caCertificates:
  hike.crt: |
    -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
    MIIFOzCCAyOgAwIBAgIUIyHpTZS7DmOv1wOXytwFAZZTJmYwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEL
    BQAwJTEjMCEGA1UEAxMaTUYgUkUgQ0Egb24gVmF1bHQgN2M3ODM2NDYwHhcNMjEw
    NDA3MTExMDIxWhcNMzEwNDA1MTExMDQwWjAlMSMwIQYDVQQDExpNRiBSRSBDQSBv
    biBWYXVsdCA3Yzc4MzY0NjCCAiIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggIPADCCAgoCggIB
    ALwivEBn9LmCc15++MbGCLoUnAbTLY60/XH8lLBa8O3u0Ay7uLIId+9P1PaWo1nP
    Ku5lYrScrczlElEKcKhTl3W54llGe7HoDsnkJRerX9gDeAMpJm099INovneTU73E
    YVtZdAB+PN8VM1/noZz2xX1MtEmoJ52tWDUnl4lyFbCY2sSsgAX5wzk9rHpzzGKF
    E1Lt6s8Df6j6Z1uJ4GIMuBKKYvAtyRYl/aznVLMmNaOO2SS6/PhF3QgwQsO3mRIZ
    s+IpHDiyOmiMM7tFYE8VD7I4S30+8oH18w6d0geXTvT7SybDRO2EDXXUalIsRzyJ
    xyH23vAmjcelYiBpHGICEOoi0eeJg+DyQB8i5gnqOMFiOC3fRRg+w4dZvOk0uQy/
    E3jMgDwJ1Xu6gcGE7SveQTyRoxq3AbAGcEHorfFp9iKKs7Y/2WSv/SsRUnDfa8kE
    OGmTvhiZoizRPkBeir6LEznf3cdG3NCYyZ/uU8vHtL+LxQ6yjIn6yC0BCNSR6d2t
    rcoOaZahr8nYn8VlukGUFS2x0szcVBEiiOgbtc35yHA6+MNafenwslg+CFjCvQzr
    U/CSHuKD6+KyowwLAX4g0i42NvOz4lKhnvCqKodXlIMPG5FRLYILZl6jAlVn7YPm
    oLfF7cvlMYjscufXD+0fP1O20CDdmVgBNIb0LVttS32rAgMBAAGjYzBhMA4GA1Ud
    DwEB/wQEAwIBBjAPBgNVHRMBAf8EBTADAQH/MB0GA1UdDgQWBBSOtPatITjgddDk
    5+0/dlUaPDW9nDAfBgNVHSMEGDAWgBSOtPatITjgddDk5+0/dlUaPDW9nDANBgkq
    hkiG9w0BAQsFAAOCAgEAbV64Ejz/VDSE0t+yaWlu283QCEvGkAImajpsAYNwrfnz
    U8w8bJMMKR0yknAwZCJOIloLHvP6CgHMKrDjc4CcbuoSVnKEjo7DbjbNjEaA9wWg
    Bbvo9Lw4MwwKkWkatFnlcxyh0SDQzYBp7CCK4CG5NYZTq7Rr1cfTNLkYu9p9sxxe
    8ER6ST5bPnfPZeVUELXoLRfgMycylBzEvbEv71S+CLOP3ACj4FGXSzFCYQtlqS8+
    U/B5vhHUvNYPwXUOScutMo402CSeB9oYN5bGTK6Uqln/viZc0bAgzATiZS+tT4qP
    k47PIsODRjnc5Xe9IyuAeIG2yvedvn/rhz0+e7RAx0sVwi3AhwdFbfRkM0nCuHYx
    Jys9HpI6+4oBR/+S61THTvP9s0vygr6/2PXHYocsqTUdTtUryyxelCRQygdXuHU8
    TsuYMiKStR/lAXEEnKQOvUV3xyDWoHGwsjGWkR4kAzUigGuQPWgpbCVBgGFnbSM1
    v8ZmLFPfVbRJNVPlDkxFluSedFdkvvVJmBG68eqQNBwIdDVqKebHES/vp3c1PYB4
    TA9LBiJQIvROTw4ZPtMOe7EuZrN5ybWIxZninFvJwoDqJHpb4s1qCy7Ru9CzsYqx
    ERx3xliLnFgGPtMIrNofvsSq4u7+/rPExYaF8vfkBtF3r50LFiy9EbqzHQtORdY=
    -----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I want to read a file called RE-ca.crt and replace it with caCertificates: {}

Comment: What do you expect from Stackexchange? You don't ask a question; you just state what you want to do. If your question is "please solve my problem", you will get a few angry looks, because it is Stackexchange's expectation that you try solving the problem yourself and show what you have tried. By the way, I am not sure I understand the sentence at the end. Do you want to replace the file `RE-ca.crt`, or perhaps the certificate that you want to add to the YAML file is contained in `RE-ca.crt`?

Answer (score -1):

I am able to accomplish task with below

printf '%s\n' '/caCertificates: {}/r RE-ca.crt' 1 '/caCertificates: {}/d' w | ed values.yaml

Comment: YAML files should be edited by YAML tools. If you had mentioned YAML in your question and what the document structure looked like, this would have been easy to fix in a robust and safe manner.